# Is there a way to write the entire request body of a POST call using cURL?

Tags: curl

Let's say my POST data looks like this in a cURL command

```
cURL -v -b cookies.txt -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:7501/rest/model/customer/getCustomerData -d {"_dynSessConf":"-1234567891235698","custId":"1109"} -o "customerData.txt"
```

The output is logged properly in `customerData.txt`. My question -

> Is there a way to log the request body too? (the json part starting from session confirmation number)?

I'd really appreciate any help because [cURL man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) doesn't help me! Thanks. Happy Holidays!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems [the closest you can get is using `--trace-ascii` option](https://superuser.com/questions/291424/how-do-you-display-post-data-with-curl), for example:

```
cURL --trace-ascii - -v -b cookies.txt ... # rest of your command...
```

The output will look something like:

> ```
> => Send header, 225 bytes (0xe1)
> 0000: POST /rest/model/customer/getCustomerData HTTP/1.1
> 0034: Host: localhost
> 0046: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1;
> 0086: Trident/6.0)
> 0094: Accept: */*
> 00a1: Referer:
> 00ac: Content-Type:application/json
> 00cb: Content-Length: 52
> 00df:
> => Send data, 52 bytes (0x34)
> 0000: {"_dynSessConf":"-1234567891235698","custId":"1109"}
> == Info: upload completely sent off: 52 out of 52 bytes
> <= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
> ```

... and then many many more lines. You could save this in a file by specifying a filename instead of `-` as the parameter, for example `--trace-ascii trace.log`