PowerShell Whatif for curl request?
I use curl to make post requests from a PowerShell-Script.
Now I've added "Whatif"-Support to my script.
I know I can use option "--trace" in curl to output the full post request data.
But (how) can I do this WITHOUT really executing the post request? (This would be the purpose of a full WhatIf-Support in my script)

Assuming you're invoking curl.exe rather than the curl alias for Invoke-WebRequest, what would you expect a WhatIf to do? Can you just wrap the call to curl with an if block? Something like function Invoke { [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)] param() if( $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("someurl" ) ) { write-host "call 'curl someurl' here" } else { write-host "do whatif stuff here" } }

You simply encapsule the action in a if
if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("Target description\value", "Operation description\value")) {
    # here the -WhatIf operations happen
}
else {
    # here the regular operations happen
}


I think your if branches are the wrong way round - ShouldProcess is $true when -WhatIf is omitted.

Thanks for your answer.
I've already done this.
What I really want is a "simulated" call to "curl.exe", which only makes an nice detailed output like in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543256/1413641
but WITHOUT really processing the request...

@mclayton yeah, I mixed up the logic with -Confirm. @jreicher that's not something Powershell can do unless you have the whatif block to output a series of preset strings simulating a real output
